# Option to “Select Image From Gallery or Camera”

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to make an option to "Select Image From Gallery or Camera". I have tried many modules but they are only providing access to the gallery directly. I am using expo tool for creating a react native application. First I want a popup to open then then the user has to pick an option then the user is redirected according to that option. If you have any suggestion, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve seen it done with React Native Image Picker, look for it in github:

https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker

**Add dependencies:**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
}
```

**Add permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**Usage**:

```
var ImagePicker = require('react-native-image-picker');

// More info on all the options is below in the README...just some common use cases shown here
var options = {
  title: 'Select Avatar',
  customButtons: [
    {name: 'fb', title: 'Choose Photo from Facebook'},
  ],
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
    path: 'images'
  }
};

/**
 * The first arg is the options object for customization (it can also be null or omitted for default options),
 * The second arg is the callback which sends object: response (more info below in README)
 */
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
  console.log('Response = ', response);

  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled image picker');
  }
  else if (response.error) {
    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
  }
  else if (response.customButton) {
    console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
  }
  else {
    let source = { uri: response.uri };

    // You can also display the image using data:
    // let source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };

    this.setState({
      avatarSource: source
    });
  }
});
```

If you would like to directly start just the camera or the gallery, use it like this:

```
// Launch Camera:
ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, (response)  => {
  // Same code as in above section!
});

// Open Image Library:
ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response)  => {
  // Same code as in above section!
});
```

Hope it helps.